# How does OBS distinguish something as a 3rd party overlay?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, obs

OBS has an option to not show 3rd party overlays (like the steam overlay) when using the game capture method and I would very much like parts of my application to, similarly, not show when being streamed.

What kind of things should I be googling to get a better idea on how OBS can tell what is an overlay and what isn't?

Comment: You don't need to google anything, it's open source: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio

Comment: My question originally indicated that I had looked at the source but since I am completely new to C++ and creating compiled applications in general I had very little idea of what exactly I was looking at. Thankfully someone generously edited that part /s

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that config setting gets piped down into the `capture_overlay` variable which is [used to delay OBS' capture until the end of swapping](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/84bf08c17199f2009b0c52ead2f5a1945ff50407/plugins/win-capture/graphics-hook/gl-capture.c#L769-L785), after any 3rd-party overlays have done their thing:

```
static inline void gl_swap_begin(HDC hdc)
{
    const bool first = swap_recurse == 0;
    ++swap_recurse;

    if (first && !global_hook_info->capture_overlay)
        gl_capture(hdc);
}

static inline void gl_swap_end(HDC hdc)
{
    --swap_recurse;
    const bool first = swap_recurse == 0;

    if (first && global_hook_info->capture_overlay)
        gl_capture(hdc);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my original comment had said that I had already looked at the source but I don't know C++ and I am not familiar with compiled applications in general but someone removed that from my question. My issue is that I don't know what I don't know. What is swapping? What is "their thing" that third party overlays are doing?